# Local ethereum node contain two different blocks but with same height

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, testnets, blocks, chain-reorganization

I am using geth node and found 2 different block with same number

> eth.getBlock("0x162ae4b189f77ed65d0be270aa8dea08d4e7dcd70432a7d1fd4e6b0fb1b301d6")

```
{
  difficulty: 1001546728,
  extraData: "0xd783010607846765746887676f312e382e33856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "0x162ae4b189f77ed65d0be270aa8dea08d4e7dcd70432a7d1fd4e6b0fb1b301d6",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x1c5d026c8e5335edd2543ef865ab1135989a4039",
  mixHash: "0x46964f111c6a11cc4750a7072563a6023a65ebc809b22df85d4b1695d983ba0b",
  nonce: "0x186079236bc7357a",
  number: 1586395,
  parentHash: "0x5adc90af1e1e4b1fb7d7ab6fcf564b565ac7ff2bc334188a00c2e0fb5b7857a4",
  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 539,
  stateRoot: "0xb5c964eca4d954d8a80ffd1b573783900d8d9be4e5639357278d6ebb26662595",
  timestamp: 1504175750,
  totalDifficulty: 1703992678143204,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}
```

> eth.getBlock("0xa9625a969941619b6a34497dc7b337df95c99378081177ea9a026a6712d266ef")

```
{
  difficulty: 1001546728,
  extraData: "0xd783010607846765746887676f312e382e33856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "0xa9625a969941619b6a34497dc7b337df95c99378081177ea9a026a6712d266ef",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x8849e2c12e153a85e84d2d202ca91f564e4bc1fa",
  mixHash: "0x174c9a4286812a71ed6ae9f0c7f312ec02075666f30c370449e13a4be9a1c9a7",
  nonce: "0xefb6d936f1e28af4",
  number: 1586395,
  parentHash: "0x5adc90af1e1e4b1fb7d7ab6fcf564b565ac7ff2bc334188a00c2e0fb5b7857a4",
  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 539,
  stateRoot: "0x242c1bb4d22e4fc0a988018b861a5746abaa6c6383938fe633838fc9fcc8e923",
  timestamp: 1504175750,
  totalDifficulty: 1703992678143204,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}
```

But only one present on etherscan (found in testnet):
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/1586395

Is it normal situation?
How to get rid of this?

Plz help.

Comment: Where did you get the hashes from? I assume that there was simply a chain reorganisation. One is part of the longest chain, the other is not.

Comment: Took hashes from local node in testnet.

Comment: Calling `eth.getBlock(1586395)` which block do you get? A chain reorganization should adjust with time.

Comment: I will receive this one
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/1586395. Don't understand, why my local node does not delete orphaned block with hash `0x162ae4b189f77ed65d0be270aa8dea08d4e7dcd70432a7d1fd4e6b0fb1b301d6` (when the valid is `0xa9625a969941619b6a34497dc7b337df95c99378081177ea9a026a6712d266ef`)

Comment: Perhaps it is included as an uncle in another block.

Comment: same happened with me. Any solution? or discussion are welcome. email pareekbhagu@gmail.com